# textarea nowrap bug in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, textarea

I found out that the following css property disables line wrapping in a html textarea.

```
textarea {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This is however causing a strange behaviour. Every few refreshes, all newlines in the textarea seem to disappear, putting all text on one line.

I'm using google chrome 12.0.x

Is this a known bug or is it more likely to be an error on my part somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser support for `white-space` on `<textarea>` is patchy at best. This is not a CSS solution, but it should do the trick:

```
<textarea name="message" wrap="off"></textarea>
```

I have added the `wrap="off"` attribute. Which doesn't seem to be *officially* supported, but has been used happily for a number of years.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. It's not as easy to implement as a css-based solution but at least this attribute does the trick.